# IMAP Commands Using Libcurl With C++ And IMAP Protocol

Tags: c++, imap, libcurl

I am creating a small email client that logs into Gmail via the Imap protocol and searches for a specific email sender the downloads the contents of that particular message.

I am using C++ and libcurl.

I have managed to login, and the response returned after the headers is the first email in my inbox.

I would like to know how to send requests/commands via the Imap protocol that can be configured to work with Libcurl. A brief reading of the RFC spec suggests the form of

```
<COMMAND> <argument>
```

and whilst this might work on the command line with telnet or curl, it is not compatible with C/C++.

I am logging in via a URL string (char * to be exact) of the form

```
"imaps://" <username> ":" <password> "@imap.gmail.com:993"
```

and passing this as the url for curl to initiate, but I am having trouble forming any other request of the same form.

What is the correct way to send commands to gmail/imap using Libcurl?

Thanks in advance

Any help is much appreciated...

Comment: Unfortunately, using IMAP via libcurl seems to be completely undocumented...  However, standard IMAP requires a *tag* before every command:  `A001 SELECT INBOX`, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say a rough syntax description would look similar to

```
imap://[<username>:<password>@]<hostname>[:portnum]/[mailboxname]
```

Comment: Yea, I have tried that and it is a little bit cumbersome, I can't seem to add any parameters along with the commands ie `imaps:// [<username>:<password>]@<imap.gmail.com>[:993]/<command>:<argument>
` doesn't seem to work.. I am thinking of using `CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY` and then using sockets to send the commands in ascii, just a bit lower level than I want to be digging

Comment: I want to be able to use the `list, examine and select` commands